# Webservice with different response. Response-Object undefined

Tags: javascript, json, web-services

I have a webservice with a JSON response. When i call the service this way:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myServiceURL/myService/" + ItemID,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.myField);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

this works great. But when i filter by name (like this):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myServiceURL/myService?$filter=Name eq 'Chubaka'",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.myField);
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

I cant get the data. Datatype from data is (object object). But when i wana get the value from data.myField it's undefined.

I checked the response with Fiddler, both answers has the result. the only diffrence i saw in raw-format is:

1 response: `{"Name" : "Chubaka"...}`

2 response: `[{"Name" : "Chubaka"....}]`

where is the diffrence an how can i get the values from the second response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In second response you get array so you have to do like this

```
data[0].Name
```

When you get array you have to interate through to get result. As in your case two different call so you can assume that both result are diffrent type. One result return single object and second result return array of object.
   You can do like this.

```
   if($.isArray(data))
   {
   for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++)
     console.log(data[0].field)
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Second response is array so you first need to get object, then only you get can the value.

```
 var i;
 for (i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
 console.log(data[i].myField);
}
```

Square brackets in json are array.

Answer (score 0):

There was a small diffrence beteween the services.

1 response: -> Returns a Person-Object

2 response: -> List of Person-Onjects (Array)

my solution:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://myServiceURL/myService?$filter=Name eq 'Chubaka'",
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            console.log(data[i].myField);
        }            
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```